# When to use PUT /carts/{cartId}

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api, pwa

When should I use the `PUT /carts/{cartId}` when I’m log as a customer to assign a guest cart to the customer https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/customer-rest-api.html#operation/quoteCartManagementV1AssignCustomerPut. If I’m trying right after I’ve log in I got a error because the customer already have a cart assign and if I try right after proccess the transaction, I’m getting 404 saying there’s not entity at the cartId

Answer (score 1):

> When should I use the PUT /carts/{cartId}

This API end point is used when you want edit the cart.

> I’m getting 404 saying there’s not entity at the cartId

It means that might be Order is placed on that cart id.

For more resolution please run below API

- GET `/V1/carts/{cartId}`

Which will return cart related data.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "createdAt": "string",
  "updatedAt": "string",
  "convertedAt": "string",
  "isActive": true,
  "isVirtual": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": 0,
      "sku": "string",
      "qty": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "price": 0,
      "productType": "string",
      "quoteId": "string",
      "productOption": {
        "extensionAttributes": {
          "customOptions": [
            {
              "optionId": "string",
              "optionValue": "string",
              "extensionAttributes": {
                "fileInfo": {
                  "base64EncodedData": "string",
                  "type": "string",
                  "name": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "downloadableOption": {
            "downloadableLinks": [
              0
            ]
          },
          "giftcardItemOption": {
            "giftcardAmount": 0,
            "customGiftcardAmount": 0,
            "giftcardSenderName": "string",
            "giftcardRecipientName": "string",
            "giftcardSenderEmail": "string",
            "giftcardRecipientEmail": "string",
            "giftcardMessage": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          },
          "configurableItemOptions": [
            {
              "optionId": "string",
              "optionValue": 0,
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            }
          ],
          "bundleOptions": [
            {
              "optionId": 0,
              "optionQty": 0,
              "optionSelections": [
                0
              ],
              "extensionAttributes": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "extensionAttributes": {}
    }
  ],
  "itemsCount": 0,
  "itemsQty": 0,
  "customer": {
    "id": 0,
    "groupId": 0,
    "defaultBilling": "string",
    "defaultShipping": "string",
    "confirmation": "string",
    "createdAt": "string",
    "updatedAt": "string",
    "createdIn": "string",
    "dob": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "gender": 0,
    "storeId": 0,
    "taxvat": "string",
    "websiteId": 0,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "customerId": 0,
        "region": {
          "regionCode": "string",
          "region": "string",
          "regionId": 0,
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        },
        "regionId": 0,
        "countryId": "string",
        "street": [
          "string"
        ],
        "company": "string",
        "telephone": "string",
        "fax": "string",
        "postcode": "string",
        "city": "string",
        "firstname": "string",
        "lastname": "string",
        "middlename": "string",
        "prefix": "string",
        "suffix": "string",
        "vatId": "string",
        "defaultShipping": true,
        "defaultBilling": true,
        "extensionAttributes": {},
        "customAttributes": [
          {
            "attributeCode": "string",
            "value": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "disableAutoGroupChange": 0,
    "extensionAttributes": {},
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "billingAddress": {
    "id": 0,
    "region": "string",
    "regionId": 0,
    "regionCode": "string",
    "countryId": "string",
    "street": [
      "string"
    ],
    "company": "string",
    "telephone": "string",
    "fax": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "vatId": "string",
    "customerId": 0,
    "email": "string",
    "sameAsBilling": 0,
    "customerAddressId": 0,
    "saveInAddressBook": 0,
    "extensionAttributes": {
      "giftRegistryId": 0
    },
    "customAttributes": [
      {
        "attributeCode": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "reservedOrderId": 0,
  "origOrderId": 0,
  "currency": {
    "globalCurrencyCode": "string",
    "baseCurrencyCode": "string",
    "storeCurrencyCode": "string",
    "quoteCurrencyCode": "string",
    "storeToBaseRate": 0,
    "storeToQuoteRate": 0,
    "baseToGlobalRate": 0,
    "baseToQuoteRate": 0,
    "extensionAttributes": {}
  },
  "customerIsGuest": true,
  "customerNote": "string",
  "customerNoteNotify": true,
  "customerTaxClassId": 0,
  "storeId": 0,
  "extensionAttributes": {}
}
```

Comment: I was more talking about this assign part of this endpoint: https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/customer-rest-api.html#operation/quoteCartManagementV1AssignCustomerPut . I'm trying to take a guest-cart and assign it to a customer for the checkout.